How to connect an Impinj RFID scanner through Java
I need to connect an Impinj RFID scanner through my Java code. I have tried many examples, but all of them use a hardcoded MAC address. Currently, I am trying to connect to the scanner using my Java program. I need to connect, disconnect, and scan RFID tags. Is there a way to do it?
